# JAX-WS: Soap-Client - Why need the WSDL to init the stubs

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, jax-ws

I have generated a SOAP-client by creating client-stubs with **wsimport** out of the WSDL of the service.

I start my client-port that way.

```
URL urlwsdl = new URL ("http://myservice?wsdl");
MyService port = new MyService_Service (urlwsdl).getTimeSeriesServicePort ();
port.foo ();
```

All is working fine.

But I am curious about the constructor of object port.

Why do I need to give it the WSDL? The stubs are generated on base of that.
Why is that necessary?

I did not try to put another WSDL into the constructor that was used to generate it.

Answer (score 1):

It not necessary to write code below line of code.

`URL urlwsdl = new URL ("http://myservice?wsdl");`

You could avoid that, it should work fine too.

The below line of code is usually required, say have received the wsdl from Test system or development system, where `URL` may be `http://myservice.test/yourservice?wsdl`, but later on when your promoted the code or shipped to some third party, that consume same service but `URL` may be different, say `http://myservice.test/yourservice?wsdl`. That's why this provision has been created `wsimport`. You could inject the URL from any property file or database or yml or ObjectFactory etc.

Your service code must be something like below,

```
    public interface AddressBookService extends ...Service {
      public String getAddressBookAddress();

      public AddressBook getAddressBook() throws ...ServiceException;

      public AddressBook getAddressBook(URL portAddress)
          throws javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException;
    }
```

And, you could use alternate code that should work as well without you explicitly specifying the port.

```
MyService service = new MyService();

// Now use the service to get a stub which implements the SDI.
port.foo();
```

And Ideally, you should not passing URL as `URL urlwsdl = new URL ("http://myservice?wsdl");`, it should be something like `URL urlwsdl = new URL ("http://myservice");`

Hope it answers your question, if not let me know, I could reattempt to answer.